# Deixar linha sempre no topo

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-datatables

Estou usando o plugin **[DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/)** e queria que uma linha ficasse sempre no topo independente da ordenação ou do search que foi feito como se ela tivesse uma "posição" estática, sempre em primeiro lugar

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Existe o plugin FixedColumns, mas não permite essa funcionalidade.

O que você pode fazer é colocar um cabeçalho com duas linhas, a segunda delas sendo a linha que você quer manter permanentemente.

Esse exemplo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluegeek9bluegeek9/Fd3ED/1/),
Extraído da pergunta [fix second row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17709134/1387277), mostra isso em ação.

Comment: Parece que essa é a melhor solução por hora